# Clojure sequence operation

Tags: clojure

How to get a new sequence from an old sequence, the elements of the new one are from the old one until a condition is met

Suppose the condition is #(> % 0)

'(1 2 3 0 3 2 0 1) returns 1, 2, 3

'(0 1 2 3) returns empty seq

'(1 2 3) returns everything.

Note it's not same as filter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want to use [take-while](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/take-while):

```
(take-while #(> % 0) '(1 2 3 0 3 2 0 1))
=> (1 2 3)
```

Comment: Or even `(take-while pos? '(1 2 3 0 3 2 0 1))`, in this specific case.

Answer (score 3):

mikera's answer looks good, but also consider `split-with` if you need to do further processing on the rest of the list.

```
=> (split-with #(> % 0) '(1 2 3 0 3 2 0 1))
[(1 2 3) (0 3 2 0 1)]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the joy of Clojure: there are so many ways to skin a cat:

```
(for [i '(1 2 3 0 3 2 0 1) :while (> i 0)] i)
=> (1 2 3)
```